# Oracle 10g trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g

I'm a newbie to Oracle (10g) databases.

My problem is that I'm not sure about a syntax and I would need to rewrite this trigger for Oracle databases:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trigger
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF :NEW.date > SYSDATE THEN
         RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20950, 'Error!');
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why not just run it and see if it works?

Comment: Do you think I would write here if the code would work?

Comment: If it doesn't, sharing the error (if you have any) or an explanation of how it misbehaves (if there's no error) would really help us help you.

Comment: An editor found mistakes nearby new, then and if, but I can't say nothing more specific.

Comment: Is this your actual (=copy-pasted) code? because `trigger` and `table` are reserved words, you can't use them as names.

Comment: Yeah, I know that. The code is edited.

Comment: Can you provide the definition of your underlying table ? It would be helpful to see the data types of the columns involved.

Comment: @KRiSTiN *"Do you think I would write here if the code would work?"* You must be new around here... :)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned you changed the names of the trigger and table, however, I'll point those out again here (just for completeness):

I see 3 mistakes:

1. "trigger" is reserved word.  I changed to "ctrigger" in below example.
2. "table" is reserved word. I changed to "junk" in below example.
3. "date" is reserved word. I changed to "cdate" in below example.
4. I assume at this time that "cdate" is a `DATE` datatype.

The below code functions properly .. try running this on your system "as is" and see if it works ?

If it does, but it still fails on your table, then we definitely need to see the definition of you table to troubleshoot further.

```
  drop table junk;

  create table junk ( id   number,
                      cdate    date );

  CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ttrigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON junk
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      IF :NEW.cdate > SYSDATE THEN
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20950, 'Error!');
      END IF;
  END;
  /
```

Test results follow:

```
  SQL  > create table junk ( id   number,
                      cdate    date );
    2
  Table created.

  Elapsed: 00:00:00.07
  SQL  > CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ttrigger
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
  ON junk
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
      IF :NEW.cdate > SYSDATE THEN
           RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20950, 'Error!');
      END IF;
  END;
  /

  Trigger created.

  Elapsed: 00:00:00.20
  SQL  > show err
  No errors.
  SQL  >
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but the problem was that the names of tables and attributes must be in quote marks.

Comment: What does that have to do with anything?  You use quote marks around table names because the table names include mixed case. That has nothing to do with the trigger code, what I wrote, or how it works ... Please post your table definition ..